# Qt как сделать, чтобы при изменении окна виджет, часть которого находится за экраном, обратно не перемещалась

Tags: c++, qt

у меня есть виджет, который выползает и частично прячется с помощью изменения координат geometry, но когда я начинаю изменять размер окна, будучи например спрятан, автоматически выползает. Также когда он прячется, все остальные виджет смещаются и появляется пустое пространство, как сделать так, чтобы еще другие виджеты при этом растягивались.

```
void MainWindow::animationv()
{
    animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->widget, "geometry");
    animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);

    animation2 = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->stackedWidget, "geometry");
    animation2 ->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);
    if (flagslid == true)
    {
        animation->setStartValue(QRect(ui->widget->x(),ui->widget->y(),ui->widget->width(),ui->widget->height()));
        animation->setEndValue(QRect(ui->widget->x()-150,ui->widget->y(),ui->widget->width(),ui->widget->height()));
        animation->setDuration(200);

        animation2->setStartValue(QRect(ui->stackedWidget->x(),ui->stackedWidget->y(),ui->stackedWidget->width(),ui->stackedWidget->height()));
        animation2->setEndValue(QRect(ui->stackedWidget->x()-150,ui->stackedWidget->y(),ui->stackedWidget->width(),ui->stackedWidget->height()));
        animation2->setDuration(200);
    }
    else
    {
        animation->setStartValue(QRect(ui->widget->x(),ui->widget->y(),ui->widget->width(),ui->widget->height()));
        animation->setEndValue(QRect(ui->widget->x()+150,ui->widget->y(),ui->widget->width(),ui->widget->height()));
        animation->setDuration(200);

        animation2->setStartValue(QRect(ui->stackedWidget->x(),ui->stackedWidget->y(),ui->stackedWidget->width(),ui->stackedWidget->height()));
        animation2->setEndValue(QRect(ui->stackedWidget->x()+150,ui->stackedWidget->y(),ui->stackedWidget->width(),ui->stackedWidget->height()));
        animation2->setDuration(200);
    }

    flagslid = !flagslid;
    //animation1->start();
    animation->start();
    animation2->start();
}
```

начальная позиция, когда запустил приложение
[image: начальная позиция, когда запустил приложение]
когда свернул виджет, другие сместились виджеты сместились и образовалось пустое пространство
[image: когда свернул виджет, другие сместились виджеты сместились и образовалось пустое пространство]

когда изменил размер окна и виджет сам вылез
[image: когда изменил размер окна и виджет сам вылез]

и из-за этого при разворачивании происходит такое
[image: и из-за этого при разворачивании происходит такое]

Answer (score 0):

Твой виджет который двигается, похоже является родителем других объектов. Поэтому когда ты изменяешь его "geometry" оно изменяется и для его дочерних объектов. Во втором случае не понятно почему так происходит, может из-за QLayout? Меняешь размер окна и все твои объекты находящиеся в лайаутах возвращаются на "родину".